# Adding CheckBox to ListView row view makes the row not clickable

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am trying to create a `ListView` similar to the Gmail app, where each row has a `CheckBox` on the left to facilitate multiple selection and actions via the contextual action bar, while at the same time, allow clicking each row to transition to another activity.

Originally, before adding the `CheckBox` the rows would indicate their selection with a light blue background color from the Holo theme I'm using and call `onListItemClick` in my `ListFragment` when clicked and `onItemLongClick` in my `OnItemLongClickListener` when long clicked.

When I add the `CheckBox` to my layout .xml file for the row view, the background no longer changes color and I no longer receive click or long click events. If I add `android:longClickable="true"` to the top `ViewGroup` in my view .xml then I start getting long click events again. But `android:clickable="true"` does not get me click events. And neither allows the background blue selection indication to return. Only the `CheckBox` itself provides visual touch indication with a blue background when touched.

What do I need to do to get the normal visual selection indication as well as click events on the `ListView` rows with the `CheckBox` in the view?

Here's the relevant portion of my view .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/) on this subject awhile back that you may find helpful.  The problem is, in fact, that adding focusable elements (like `CheckBox` or `Button`) disables the ability to click the overall list item and their focusability has to be disabled.  You should not add any `clickable` flags to the main layout either.

Comment: Thanks! That was the right combination. I had been playing with the focusable and clickable values, but it was only when the focusable="false" AND no clickable values were added that it now works.

Comment: indeed.... and how to capture the event of that Checkbox? for instance, once it's clicked I want to grab the name of that line.... @Devunwired ?

Answer (score 0):

While adding checkbox in CAB please make it focusable="false", this will solved the problem of only one time called onItemCheckedStateChanged.